# Accessing a DialogFragment's parent activity

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android

I have a DialogFragment displayed in my app. When the user clicks the positive button on this dialog, I want to modify the UI on the parent activity. What would be the best way to do this?

Unfortunately I don't have the code to hand as it's at work, but it is essentially this:

I have `ItemDisplayActivity` which extends the `Activity` class, and `ItemCommentDialog` which extends the `DialogFragment` class. When the positive button on `ItemCommentDialog` is clicked, I want to modify `ItemDisplayActivity`'s UI.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way if for the `DialogFragment` to include a communication interface that the parent activity implements.  The fragment calls back to the parent through that interface.

Have a look at [this Android developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) which demonstrates this technique in the course of explaining how to use dialog fragments.